# Bootstrap stacked navbar dropdown in Asp.net

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I am new in bootstrap.
I am trying to code my `Asp.net` page using bootstrap 
I want create drop down on the left side of my page. I am referring the `css` code form the bootstrap website

till now I tried this
Code:

```
 <div class=" nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
     <ul class="navbar nav nav-pills nav-stacked"> 
     <li class="dropdown"><a href="#"  class="dropdown-toggle" id="button">Navigation<span class="caret"></span></a>

     <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="menu">
     <li><a href="#">sub item 1</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">sub item 2</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">sub item 3 </a></li>
     </ul></li> 
      <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
     </ul>
     </div>
```

When I run the code sub item 1,2,3 hides under Navigation.... but when I try to click on the navigation menu nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

see i am also new in bootstrap. change your code to this. and tell me it works or not. i have not tried this.

```
    <div class=" nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
         <ul class="navbar nav nav-pills nav-stacked"> 
         <li class="dropdown"> <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
        Dropdown
        <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>

         <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul></li> 
          <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
         </ul>
         </div>
```

Comment: <data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true"> i tried this properties before with the button. it says it is not valid property  i need something that will hold those properties

Comment: change your browser. try chrome. 'aria-expanded' browser supported. and 'data-toggle' is bootstrap related..

1. for 'aria-expanded' change your browser and then check.
2. for 'data-toggle' check your bootstrap js and jquery file are getting load properly..